# All of a sudden my Scala code expects `;` at the end of each statement

Tags: scala, sbt

So, basically everything was fine till my last invocation of `sbt compile`... 2 days back.

But now when I invoke `sbt compile`, it is expecting every statement to end with `;`.

Example:

Following causes problem,

```
package me.example.sample

import java.util.UUID
```

Error,

```
'{' expected but 'import' found.
[error] import java.util.UUID
        ^
```

But this works fine,

```
package me.example.sample;

import java.util.UUID;
```

How do I solve this issue ?

I am running `Scala 2.11.5` with `Oracle java 1.8.0_40`.

Comment: Can you please try sbt clean command and then compile your code and see what is happening ?

Comment: @Nishan Well... I got it... the culprit was `IntelliJ`... Somehow the `line ending` setting was set to `CR` or `\r` which works on `Mac` and I am working on Linux which works with `LF` or `\n` line endings. And it was causing Scala compiler to be very very confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So... In case some one else faces the same problem in future.

Basically Scala avoids `semicolons` by using `line-endings` as statement separators.

So... In scala following two things are equivalent:

```
println( "Hello" ); prinln( "World" )
```

And

```
println( "Hello" )
prinln( "World" )
```

Now, line endings are differently represented in three most popular operating systems.

```
Windows - CRLF - `\r\n`  
Linux   - LF   - `\n`  
Mac     - CR   - `\r`
```

Now, depending on your operating environment, Scala compiler will expect to have corresponding line endings as `statement separators` otherwise it will be very very confused.

So... In case you get this sort of problem. Please check your line endings.